# Azure-Mobile-Sync SDk android neglecting base url

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

Azure android sdk neglecting the baseURL.  `http:IP/baseName` Neglecting the baseName. It occurs only during the `POST`. `GET` working successfully. Does anyone have similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

In my application 
 baseurl=  http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/myapp/

for the get request the url is

http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/myapp/tables/todoitem

but for post,

http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/tables/todoitem

While sending  a post request azure sdk is truncating the url by removing "/myapp".

I think the issue is in line 137 in MobileServiceHttpClient class inside the azure sdk.

Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse(mClient.getAppUrl().toString()).buildUpon();
        uriBuilder.path(path);

But i couldn't resolve this bug yet.